# Initializing QColorDialog with Qt::black always returns black

Tags: c++, qt

I am creating a QColorDialog using the static function like so:

```
QColor c = QColorDialog::getColor(Qt::black);

if (c.isValid())
{
    std::cout << c.red() << std::endl;
    std::cout << c.green() << std::endl;
    std::cout << c.blue() << std::endl;
}
```

If I now choose a color in the dialog and press OK, it always returns black (as in RGB(0, 0, 0)). Also the RGB values in the dialog are not updating.

[image]

If I create the dialog like this:

```
QColor c = QColorDialog::getColor(Qt::white);
```

Everything works as expected.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: No it doesn't. Parent should default to nullptr anyway. https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcolordialog.html#getColor.

Comment: post minimum valid code to reproduce

Comment: I can not confirm this behavior using Qt 5.13.1. I tried exactly your line of code and `qDebug()` returns exactly the color that I selected. Doesn't matter which default-color I specify.

Comment: Sorry my bad. Is that enough? I didn't want to post the whole Qt setup scaffolding to create a GUI app.

Comment: I can also not confirm it on Windows with Qt 5.5. It works exactly as it should

Comment: Could not reproduce too. It works fine (Windows 10, Qt 5.12.1, MinGW_64).

Comment: Nor on Qt 5.11.0 - ubuntu

Comment: Operating error? These color dialogs are tricky :)

Comment: The chosen color in the image is black!!

Comment: If you choose the color in the selection area where I pointed the arrow. Does it work? I am using Qt 5.14 on Linux

Comment: @G.M. Gosh you are right! I was expecting that to change the value but of course it shouldn't. Alright that's plenty embarassing, I'll head back to my cave. Thanks everyone!

Comment: @tde I was guessing that Qt::black would have been 0 (it is not) and would have been interpreted as nullptr instead of QColor, though that did not really match the description.

Comment: @tde it would be nice if you could accept the answer. Cheers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your Value in the HSV is 0! Thats why all is black. [image]

Comment: You got it. I am an idiot. Thanks!

Comment: Well if it makes you feel better, your question - and the answer - just made me fix my color issue, too ;)